# TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: helvetica whmcs

Tags: hosting, whmcs

i have installed whmcs but i cannot process invoice.
This is the error at checkout TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: helvetica whmcs

Comment: Do you use default whmcs template Six?

Comment: no i am not using the default template @wesamly

Comment: Either remove the custom font from code to use the default font, or add the custom font to: whmcs_dir/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts

Answer (score 3):

Download the font files from the URL below.
http://www.whmcs.com/download/106/dejavusans_tcpdf_font

- Upload into the **/vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf/fonts/** (if you are using
  WHMCS 6.0 or 6.1) or **/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts/** (if you are
  using WHMCS 6.2 or newer) folder.
- If you don't find fonts folder,
  create folder called **fonts**.
- Specify the custom font name dejavusans in Setup > General Settings >
  Invoices > TCPDF Font.